# Re-link (/import) Daum PotPlayer bookmarks saved as Registry INI

Tags: windows-registry, daum-pot-player

So I spent hours bookmarking some videos on Potplayer. However one day, all of my bookmarks disappeared.

I've looked in my registry and under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Daum\PotplayerMini64, Daum, I've got some BMItems which I think correspond to the original bookmarks. I've also got a BMList, however there are 23 items in there, which tell me the files for the BMItems I believe. However I've got 300 BMItems and only 23 files in BMList.

Where can I find a proper BMList? (with file names for all 300 BMItems)

[image: Image. A screenshot of the Windows registry. The registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software, Daum, PotplayerMini64, B M Item underscore 100, is currently open. However, multiple keys with the format B M Item underscore number are present. They are listed in order as 0, 1, 10, 100, 1 0 1, 1 0 2 and 1 0 3. Under the open B M Item underscore 100 registry key, there is a list of additional entries named 0 to 25. Each entry has a value consisting of a random six digit number, an asterisk, the word Bookmark followed by a short number, such as four, a second asterisk, and finally an extremely long number. These entries appear as one word, without spaces, except between Bookmark and the short number. The long, final numbers superficially appear to be the same across all the entry values]